# Why does not it display UITableView anymore when embed UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am new to iOS development. I am learning Swift now. I currently have a problem that my tableView does not display anything anymore after I add a navigation view controller. I don't understand why. Please help me experts!!

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let mainVC = ViewController()
    let navigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainVC)
    window?.rootViewController = navigationVC;
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Code in ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet var myTable: UITableView!
var items: [String] = ["Date Picker","List of Data","Slider","Show Image", "Web Display"];

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSLog("Hello World at console");
    var nib = UINib(nibName: "ListCell", bundle: nil)
    myTable?.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ListCell")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard use its instantiate method, and set a storyboardID of your controller in storyboard

```
YourController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ControllerStoryboardId"];
```

and if xib file

```
YourController *vc = [[YourController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```